# crawl pictures from web site with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, extract, html-content-extraction

I want to crawl the image of each bottle of wine from web site of **vinnicolas** and save it in an svc file.

unfortunately, I got some errors :

Spider : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6424305

pipelines.py. : https://gist.github.com/nahali/6434932

settings.py :

Comment: settings.py :  https://gist.github.com/nahali/6434945

Comment: what errors do you have? you could add the error log in the gist as new file

Comment: In your spider I do not see where you set `item["image_urls"]`. You need to set a list or image URLs to fetch in `item["image_urls"]`

Comment: i think i have a list of image in item["image_urls"], but I am a newbee, so I've just tryed to follow http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/images.html

Comment: is it you paul tremberth ?

Comment: so no idea about my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `parse_wine_page` does not set the "image_urls" field value in the items, so the middleware will not download any images

```
import urlparse
...

    def parse_wine_page(self, reponse):
        ...
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        content = hxs.select('//*[@id="glo_right"]')
        for res in content:
            ...
            #item ["Image"]= map(unicode.strip, res.select('//div[@class="pro_detail_tit"]//div[@class="pro_titre"]/h1/text()').extract())
            item['image_urls'] = map(lambda src: urlparse.urljoin(response.url, src), res.select('./div[@class="pro_col_left"]/img/@src').extract())
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Also make sure your `Projetvinnicolas3Item` class has "images" and "image_urls" Fields()

Comment: merci Paul, ça mache j'ai eu les liens mais je veux qu'ils téléchargé dans un fichier et le visualiser sur le svc

Comment: the CSV file should contain the filepaths to the images in the "images" column. I don't know if or how you can display the images in your CSV viewer